# How to access a file in a directory from other directory, when both are in same parent directory with HTML

Tags: html, css

[image]

How can i access 2.html from 1.html? When i click on a link given in 1.html.
and both the directories are in same directory.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "access"? You mean a link? (In that case it's `../dir 2/2.html`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (place in 1.html):

```
<a href="../dir2/2.html">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if dir1 and dir2 are in the same parent directory then this is how you access 2.html from 1.html:

`<a href="../dir2/2.html">link to 2.html</a>`

hope it helped :)

Comment: @kevin — Yes it will. ``\``, OTOH, is specific to Windows file systems.

Comment: i've modified my post, check it out please

Comment: `../` is for *everything*, it is the standard for URLs. It isn't *nix specific.